# C++ Qt library shiboken bound pyd cannot be imported

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyside

I'm trying to build the example `widgetbinding` from pyside's examples. I successfully built the module `pyd` but I cannot import the module after I built the `pyd`. I also tried my own C++ Qt library and got the same error.

I use cmake to build the binding module:

```sh
cmake -B ./build -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
cd build
nmake
nmake install
cd .. # back to the directory my pyd installed
ipython # start testing the importing

In [1]: import wiggly
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8a2812855881> in <module>
----> 1 import wiggly

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing wiggly: 找不到指定的模块。
```

trying to include the module in python

[image]

I'm on Windows 10 and using Qt 6.0.2, Shiboken6.0.1 and PySide6.0.1. The python on my machine is download directory from python.org.(Does it matters that I'm not using a python built on vs2019 on my own?)

I can successfully build the samplebinding from pyside6/examples, which doesn't contain any Qt related C++ code. Able to import the module in python

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution.

I got this ImportError because I'm testing the pyd on IPython using one single line:

```py
import wiggly
```

but the pyd in this case(built as a Qt library) have dependencies on dlls like `pyside6.abi3.dll`, `QtWidgets.dll`, etc.

So when I import PySide6.Qwidgets before importing wiggly, It works!
Now I write:

```py
import PySide6.QtWidget
import wiggly
```